# Need to fix error not found in module - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm practicing angular, but received this error while compiling my code:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.component.css' in 'D:\hello-world-app\src\app'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

My app.component.html

```html
<h1>Angular</h1>
<courses></courses>
```

My courses.component.ts

```js
// tslint:disable-next-line: import-spacing
import{Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'courses', //<courses>
  template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})
export class CoursesComponent {

}
```

My app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'hello-world-app';
}
```

My app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Is there a file called `app.component.css` in the same directory as `app.component.ts`?

Comment: See if `D:\hello-world-app\src\app\app.component.css` file exists, if not adjust the path in your component

Comment: i dont have a file named app.component.css sir @Jacquesジャック

Comment: @Rikin I dont have that file sir. what to do

Comment: Delete the line `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain sir why i got that error? @Jacquesジャック

Comment: Because angular was trying and failing to find (*resolve*) that file. As such it was failing to compile. (Just as the error states)

Comment: @Jacquesジャック ok thanks sir

Comment: if your intent is to add css style to your app.component you could alternatively 1) leave the styleUrls property/value within the app.component.ts @Component decorator and 2) add the missing app.component.css to same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is failing to find (*resolve*) the file, just as the error states. In order to fix the error, you need to either add the file, or delete the line `styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']`

If you do not want to avoid the file reference and are using [angular cli](https://angular.io/cli/) (if you're not, you probably should be), you can use `--inlineStyle=true` when generating a component. Granted, if you're using angular cli, the css file *should have* been created when the component was generated.

Odds are either you copy pasted some stuff, or mistakenly deleted that file. Either way, Angular will always complain when it can't find something you're referencing. (Much like pretty much every other programming framework/system/language)